# Delete UITableView Cell using animation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, core-graphics

I want to delete UITableView's cell but with animation. I want animation like explained below:

Need to draw a line on the content of UITableViewCell, & when my touch ends the content will disappear & after that the cell will be removed. You can get an idea from the image attached here.[image]

I've thought to achieve this with this flow:

1. I need to draw a line on the content, using CoreGraphics
2. In `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event` , I will invoke step3
3. Call `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Let me know if I'm wrong in some way or you have some other alternatives.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just google it and got best solution from http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13

check this Full Tutorial i found screen bellow:-

[image]

follow link Example Hope you got your solution

at the bellow of Code also Provide Demo in link and while you courser drag left to right side of Cell it's Cell Appear Green with Horizontal line. And while you Drag courser left to right then Cell Remove from Table View its A amazing Demo.